# Prove that $\left \| \vec{x}-\vec{a} \right \|+\left \| \vec{x}-\vec{b} \right \|=\left \| \vec{a} \right \|-\left \| \vec{b} \right \|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $V$ be a vector space with inner product and $\vec{a},\vec{b}\epsilon V-\left \{ 0 \right \}$.

I'm asked to prove that

if $\left \| \vec{x}-\vec{a} \right \|+\left \| \vec{x}-\vec{b} \right \|=\left \| \vec{a} \right \|-\left \| \vec{b} \right \|$  if and only if, x=na+mb, n+m=1

In the previous question I succesfully proved, using the Parallelogram law,
that

$\left \| \vec{a}+\vec{b} \right \|=\left \| \vec{a} \right \|+\left \| \vec{b} \right \|$ if and only if $\vec{a}=λ\vec{b}, λ>0$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.

For example, let $V=\mathbb{R}^2,a=x=(1,0)$ and $b=(0,1)$. Clearly $x$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. However, we have $||x-a||+||x-b||=\sqrt2\neq0=||a||-||b||$.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad I misread what I was asked to prove. It said prove that x=na+mb, with n+m=1.. How about that? I thought that I could use again the Parallelogram law but I can't proceed..

Comment: In my example, $x=1a+0b$ violates your property. So this is still not true. Maybe we need to presume further that "$a=\lambda b$" where "$\lambda\ge1$".

Comment: Thanks for the response eric I will try proving it for $λ>=1$